# Dynamic multiple form submisssions with hyperlink using anchor tag in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, anchor

I am working on Struts 2 app and displaying data in JSP using `<s:iterator>` and each record which displays in JSP has a hyperlink link.

I want to submit some data into some other JSP page using this link and using POST method.

Below is my code snippet in JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="#request.Forums">
<s:property value="user_name"/>
<s:form action="displayForum" >
<s:hidden name="id" ></s:hidden>
<s:hidden name="subject" ></s:hidden>
<a  href="javascript:this.form.id"><s:property value="subject"/></a>
</s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

I have tried this using form id with JavaScript as `document.forms["formid"].submit` but my iterator is not givig a single id as it's vary dynamically.

Note: I have used `<s:url>` insted of `<s:form>` but it's appending the form parameter values to the URL. But my requirement is to send form parameters as hidden variables.

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Generate unique id for you `<s:form>` like that

```
<s:iterator value="#request.Forums" status="stat">
   <s:form id="formid%{#stat.index}" action="displayForum">
       <a href="javascript:submitForm('formid<s:property value="#stat.index"/>')">submit</a>
   </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

and pass this id to you javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `id` in your form:

```
<s:form id="formid" action="displayForum">
...
</s:form>
```

And inside you form, put an anchor with a javascript call:

```
<s:form...>
...
<a href="javascript: submit_my_form();">Submit</a>
</s:form>
```

And then put in your javascript code:

```
function submit_my_form() {
    document.forms["formid"].submit();
}
```

Edit: For more information, you can search in google: *submit a form with javascript*. For example: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

But I have tried this way and I have the issue to retrieve the formid's dynamically as it has multiple forms because of <s:iterator> and the javascript is taking the first formid.

Comment: @venkata The best alternative for what you want it Aleksandr one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understood your question, if you wanna submit a form, you should use `submit`, whatever use `javascript` or `s:submit`, but i will suggest you to try it like this:

```
<s:iterator value="#request.Forums" var="forum" status="status">
    <s:property value="#forum.user_name"/>
    <s:form action="displayForum" method="POST">
        <s:hidden name="id" value="#forum.id"></s:hidden>
        <s:hidden name="subject" value="#forum.subject"></s:hidden>
        <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```